# Dataframe sorting twice

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this `df` (its an example):

```
item    item_s   money
A9       200      10
A1       201      100
A9       202      30
A2       203      40
A3       204      50
A9       205      60
A1       206      70
A3       207      80
A1       220      90
```

What Im looking for? I want sorting twice:

**Sorting 1:** I want to group according to the largest sum of `money` according to `item`. Like this:

```
item    item_s   money
 A1      220      90
 A1      206      70
 A1      201      100
 A3      204      50      
 A3      207      80
 A9      205      60
 A9      202      30
 A9      200      10
 A2      203      40
```

This sort is because `A1` `money` sum is `260`, for `A3` is `130`, for `A9` is `100` and for `A2` is `40`.

**Sorting 2:** Within each `item`, order them from largest to smallest (**This is the final `df` that Im looking for**).

```
item    item_s   money
 A1      201      100
 A1      220      90
 A1      206      70
 A3      207      80      
 A3      204      50
 A9      205      60
 A9      203      40
 A9      202      30
 A2      200      10
```

What I tried:

```
df.groupby(['item','item_s'])['money'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(20)
```

But I get only a sorting by `money` and with a view that is not what I expected (because some `item` data doesn't appear explicit and `money` column header doesn't appear explicit either):

```
item    item_s   
 A1      201      100 
         220      90
 A3      207      80
 A1      206      70    
 A9      205      60
 A3      204      50
 A2      203      40
 A9      202      30
 A2      200      10
```

Comment: In this case, instead of grouping on `tracks`, you would group on `item`, and instead of `.sort_values(["max","score"])` you would write `.sort_values(["max","money"])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

1. assign a column that contains the `sum` of money per group.
2. `sort_values` on the new column and money
3. drop the unnecessary column

```
>>> df.assign(total=df.groupby("item")["money"].transform("sum")).sort_values(["total","money"],ascending=False).drop(columns="total")

  item  item_s  money
1   A1     201    100
8   A1     220     90
6   A1     206     70
7   A3     207     80
4   A3     204     50
5   A9     205     60
2   A9     202     30
0   A9     200     10
3   A2     203     40
```